# how do I create a sidebar that auto fits the section height of my page in Squarespace?

Tags: html, css, sidebar, squarespace

[image: screenshot showing sidebar overlapping footer]

I'm taking over a site in Squarespace that had an existing code for a sidebar.  However, the sidebar is different on each page because the section heights are different.  How do I control the sidebar height to fit each section height?

I tried using section id from each section to change the sidebar height for each page but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
 <div class="sidebar">
 <h4>Topics</h4>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#policy">Policy & Advocacy <i class="fad fa-angle- 
 double-right"></i></a></li>
 <li><a href="#partnership">Partnerships <i class="fad fa-angle- 
 double-right"></i></a></li>
 <li><a href="#annual">Annual Reports <i class="fad fa-angle-double- 
 right"></i></a></li>
 <li><a href="#get">Get Involved <i class="fad fa-angle-double- 
 right"></i></a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

```
//sidebar
[data-section-id="61a0efc242660c7166c10af7"] {
  .sidebar {
  position:relative;
  background:#7B7D81;
  height:58vh;
  padding-top:100px;
  @media @mobile{
      height:auto;
      padding:20px;
    border-radius:3px;
    }
  h4{
    color:#fff !important;
    z-index:999;
    position:relative;
  }
  ul{
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    li{
      margin:5px 0;
      a{
        font-weight:500;
        transition: all ease-in-out 150ms !important;
        -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 150ms !important;
        -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 150ms !important;
        -ms-transition: all ease-in-out 150ms !important;
        color:#fff;

        &:hover{
          color:#FDD505;
          font-weight:600;
          i{
            opacity:0.5;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  &:before{
      position:absolute;
      content:'';
      width:200%;
      height:150%;
      background:#7B7D81;
      top:-20%;
      right:0;
    @media @mobile{
      display:none;
    }
  }
}
}
```